# VS 2010 File path too long error on build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path, long-integer

My projects fails on build with this error.

> Error 1   Copying file sampleApp\App\sampleApp\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\folder7\folder8\folder9\file.xcu
>
> to
> obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\sampleApp\App\sampleApp\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\folder7\folder8\folder9\file.xcu
> failed.
>
> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
> qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
> directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Is there a way to change the maximum allowed character on VS 2010

Comment: Can you move your solution from folder9 to folder1 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - perhaps you could implement a folder shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

This length limitation is acknowledged my Microsoft itself, [as you can see here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation)

This is a growing concern among the developers when there is a deeply-nested project hierarchy. But we do have some work-around for this, like using Peter's [LongPath](https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath) library.

Since as from what I can see from your dump, just to move an arbitrary file to the debug location is simple. You can do this as a pre-build task, create an [Inline Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601) and use the `LongPath` library instead of `System.IO`

I really hope this helps.